# validate number upto two decimal point

Tags: regex

I want to validate a number as decimal up to two decimal and minimum range is greater than 0.00 and max range is up to 99.99

Decimal is optional in a number that is user can input 10.00 as 10.

This is what I tried:

```
^\d+(\.\d{2})?$
```

Comment: Please post your attempt. Also, `99.999` is 3 decimals, was that a typo?

Comment: I tried as ^\d+(\.\d{2})?$

Comment: @RakeshSawant You should also put the language you're using (or application/environment) as well as what's wrong with the attempt you have. This will encourage people to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try the regex:

```
^[1-9]\d?(?:\.\d{0,2})?$
```

`^` is the beginning of line anchor which matches the beginning of a line.

`[1-9]` is any number from 1 to 9.

`\d?` is for two digit numbers.

`(?:\.\d{0,2})?` is an optional non-capturing group for the decimals accepting at least one decimal and at most 2 decimals.

`$` is the end of line anchor which matches the end of a line and makes sure there are no other digits after the last decimal digit.

Comment: I tried ^[0-9]{1,3}\.?([0-9]{1,2})?$ it is working but it is allowing 0.00 which should not

Comment: @RakeshSawant You did not use the regex I suggested, did you?

Comment: It's correct except it doesn't allow `10.`. You should use `{0,2}` quantifier for decimal part. Nevertheless, +1.

Comment: @M42 Oops, I don't know how I thought there ought to be a number after the decimal. Thanks, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RegularExpressionValidator for this

Try This

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revFee" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="Only 2 digits after decimal."  ValidationGroup="Payment"
        ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d*(\.\d{0,2})?$"
        ControlToValidate="txtFee" 
        Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="Red">
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```